# How to clear selected objects in NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the following code that currently clears all the objects in my NSManagedObjectContext:

```c
- (void)clearObjectList:(NSString *)identifier
{
    // TODO: Delete any entries with the identifier at the start of the object's name
    NSLog(@"Clearing the URL list...");

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest * fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"URL" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    NSArray * result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
    for (id basket in result)
    {
        // Code here to check if we should delete this object
        [context deleteObject:basket];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        //abort();
    }
}
```

The Data model I have for URL is:

```
dateAccessed: Date
        name: String
         url: String
```

I want to access the objects key `name` to determine if it should be removed.  How do I access this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(URL *basket in result)
{
    if([basket.name isEqualToString:identifier])
        [context deleteObject:basket];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When looping through your results, you know that all you'll get back is `NSManagedObject`s. Or, if you've created NSManagedObject subclasses, you'll only get back `URL` objects. Thus, you can replace `id` with either `NSManagedObject *` or `URL *` in your for loop.

If you did create subclasses, which I'd recommend, you can access the `name` with dot notation: `basket.name`. If you didn't, you can access it by calling `[basket valueForKey:@"name"]`.